# CocoaPods integration for Urban Airship

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, cocoapods, urbanairship.com

I have integrated pods for AFNetworking successfully. Now I want to integrate Urban Airship using CocoaPods. Can anybody help me?

I don't know how to use same Podfile to integrate another library. It would be great if someone please tell me step by step process to integrate Urban Airship for push notification using CocoaPods.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer which i provided it worked at your end or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps :**

- Add pod 'UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK' to your pod file(Just below AFNetworking Line)
- Open terminal
- Go to your project folder(where pod file exists)
- Run Pod update..

Thats it. Let me know if you face any difficulty in any step.

Comment: Gimbal Supports for cocoapods? Can we able to install Gimbal-ios-sdk from cocoapods? we tried to do it, but failed. Anyone help me please

Comment: Refer my previous comment.